# Find maximum and minimum value of inverse function .

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

[image]

We have to find maximum and minimum value of $x^2 +y^2$

My try

[image]

how can I proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lfloor xy \rfloor=n$, then

$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{1-x^2y^2} = \tan \frac{n\pi}{4}$$

> You've checked that no solutions for $0\le xy \le 1$, hence the tangent value must be negative which is achievable when $n=3,7,\ldots, 4k-1, \ldots$

Now
\begin{align}
  \frac{x^2+y^2}{1-x^2y^2} &= \tan \left( k\pi-\frac{\pi}{4} \right) \\
  x^2+y^2 &= x^2y^2-1
\end{align}

The required minimum value occurs when $xy=3$, therefore

$$\fbox{$\min \{ x^2+y^2 \}=8$}$$

and there're no maxima.

Comment: Why minimum occurs at xy=3

Comment: $x^2+y^2=x^2y^2-1$ increases with $xy$.  Now pick the minimal possible $n$, i.e. $n=3 \le xy < 4$.